# msbuild ignores static code analysis errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I want to use some static analysis NuGet libraries (StyleCop, RefactorEssentials) and, in order to enforce the rules, I want to use “Treat warning as errors” project level option.

I also need to have the same behavior when building the solution by using MSBuild.
I tested such a setup and in Visual Studio 2015 the build fails as expected but
I cannot get the same behavior with MSBuild.

I tried to run the following MSBuild command: `MSBuild test.sln /t:clean,build /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true` but the build gives 0 warnings and errors. 
Moreover, after I build the solution using the above MSBuild command, the visual Studio also reports successful builds even if the errors are still there and reported in Errors List view. I have to rebuild the solution in Visual Studio to make it fail again due to analyzers errors.

Any idea why i have this behavior and what should I do to get the same behavior from MSBuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you don’t specify Configuration and Platform, the configuration and platform are different between build in VS and MSBuild tool, so code analysis rules are different.

The RunCodeAnalysis argument is used to enable code analysis and run code analysis with specific rule (project property=>Code Analysis, different Configuration and Platform have different setting). For this way, you can add true property in project file (PropertyGroup) or specify this argument directly for MSbuild command.

For StyleCop code analysis:

1. Install [stylecop.MSbuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/) package
2. (Treat waring as error) Add `<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>` to PropertyGroup of project file or specify this argument directly for MSBuild command

Also settings of Build (project property) are also base on Configuration and Platform.

Comment: Thanks, is works. More about step 2 here: http://sarangasl.blogspot.ro/2015/06/configure-stylecop-with-msbuild-to.html